# Angular: Method for accessing queryParams in ngOnInit is not working, when calling a routing method with queryParams

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, query-string

I am currently learning Angular Routing and got this error. So, in the `course` component, I tried modifying the web contents using queryParams and variable `editMode: boolean` - its default value is `false`.

[Stackblitz code link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-jrdc2r)

https://github-jrdc2r.stackblitz.io/Course/101?edit=true

**course.component.ts**

```
export class CourseComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(private service: CoursesService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

  course: any;
  courseId: any;
  routeParamObservable: any;
  queryParamObservable: any;
  editMode: boolean = false;

  addQueryParam() {
    this.router.navigate(['/Course', this.courseId], { queryParams: { edit: true } });
  }

  //saveUpdateNameChange() {
    //this.router.navigate(['/Course', this.courseId]);
  //}

  // --------------------------ERROR is here----------------------------------
  //Route working but accessing query-params using observables is not working
   saveUpdateNameChange() {
     this.router.navigate(['/Course', this.courseId], { queryParams: { edit: false } });
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.courseId = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    // this.courseId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    // this.course = this.service.courses.find(x => x.id == this.courseId);

    this.routeParamObservable = this.route.paramMap.subscribe({
      next: (param) => {
        this.courseId = param.get('id');
        this.course = this.service.courses.find(x => x.id == this.courseId);
      }
    })

    // when manually refreshing the page
    this.router.navigate(['/Course', this.courseId]);

    //accessing query-params using snapshot //! This doesn't work
    // this.editMode = Boolean(this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('edit'));

    //accessing query-params using observables 
    this.queryParamObservable = this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe({
      next: (param) => {
        this.editMode = Boolean(param.get('edit'));
        console.log(this.editMode);
      }
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.routeParamObservable.unsubscribe();
    this.queryParamObservable.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

**course.component.html**

```
<div class="course-container">
    <div>
        <img src="{{course.image}}" width="560" height="280">
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1 *ngIf="!editMode" style="text-align: center;">{{course.name}}</h1>
        <div *ngIf="editMode" style="text-align: center;">
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="course.name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="course-details">
        <div style="margin: 0px 10px;"><b>Author: </b>{{course.author}}</div>
        <div style="margin: 0px 10px;"><b>Duration: </b>{{course.duration}}</div>
        <div style="margin: 0px 10px;"><b>Type: </b>{{course.type}}</div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 0px 10px;">
        <h2>Price: {{course.price}}$</h2>
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 20px 10px;">
        <p>{{course.description}}</p>
    </div>

    <button (click)="addQueryParam()" *ngIf="!editMode">Edit</button>
    <button (click)="saveUpdateNameChange()" *ngIf="editMode">Save Update</button>
</div>
```

So here, after calling `addQueryParam()` method .

- when I am trying to save the change by calling
  `saveUpdateNameChange() {this.router.navigate(['/Course', this.courseId], { queryParams: { edit: false } });}` - method with
  queryParams => routing is working but the method for accessing queryParams
  in ngOnInit is not working and the console log is not showing false.
- While when calling `saveUpdateNameChange() {this.router.navigate(['/Course', this.courseId]);}` - method without
  queryParams => routing and method for accessing queryParams in
  ngOnInit is working completely fine and can see the console log is showing
  false.

So, how the method for accessing queryParams in ngOnInit is working when calling a method without queryParams and it's not working when calling a method with queryParams for this specific case?

*PS: Please forgive me if my question is wrong.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

false is also getting logged in the console. I just checked https://github-jrdc2r.stackblitz.io/Course/101

Seems like issue is with your conversion into boolean. Boolean always returning true in case of false also.

Replace code inside of queryparamMap with below

```
    console.log(param.get('edit'));
    var d = param.get('edit') || '';
    this.editMode = JSON.parse(d);
    console.log(this.editMode);
```

Point is try JSON.parse for your boolean conversion.

Comment: Thank you. I was wrong about the usage of Boolean() method. I assumed Boolean('false') returns false, which was the wrong.